# Kinesis GetRecords API returns empty Records[] array

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to read the records using `aws-kinesis` `get_records` but it returns empty array[] record.

Found no clear solution anywhere.

I have tried with `CLI` and `Boto3` by setting up a proper required credentials.

I have tested with 2 flows:

1. Created stream --> inserted record using put_record --> and based on the Iterator read record using get_records, Working awsome!! But,
2. When I try to read record using get_records directly. Returns empty array[].

````
aws kinesis describe-stream --stream-name TestDataStream

```get shard iterator
aws kinesis get-shard-iterator --stream-name TestDataStream --shard-id shardId-000000000000 --shard-iterator-type LATEST

```get-records
aws kinesis get-records --shard-iterator xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```RESULT - empty 
{
    "Records": [], 
    "NextShardIterator": "AAAAAAAAAAGpDl4WXIHlx3gGq52/EDxEG5CkQU57gf/tR9W+6Gm2KWCCDp8baoE+Basz0OENMdQFhRCQp/cwp0pVMA8CtGwd+WdfXeIucK6d83Vc+DzIAnw/DGqQ4nJSRcFJg3za5+eAHm9hH781vSEYa0ivcbgfhjskudkugd/phhnb9gVJQRyGfNmAVli+htmQkZwYgaTji05M4r9C9RKVn+c49E2rZ8D", 
    "MillisBehindLatest": 0
}



```PYTHON CODE

client = boto3.client('kinesis', aws_access_key_id='xxxxxxx',
                              aws_secret_access_key='xxxxxxx/',
                              region_name='us-east-1')
        streamName = "TestDataStream"
        response = client.describe_stream(StreamName=streamName)
        print("::stream description::", response)
        my_shard_id = response['StreamDescription']['Shards'][0]['ShardId']
        shard_iterator = client.get_shard_iterator(StreamName=streamName,
                                                   ShardId=my_shard_id,
                                                   ShardIteratorType='TRIM_HORIZON')
        my_shard_iterator = shard_iterator['ShardIterator']
        print("::shard_iterator::", my_shard_iterator)
        record_response = client.get_records(ShardIterator=my_shard_iterator,
                                                 Limit=30)
        print(":: Records ::", record_response)
````

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? I'm experiencing it as well.